# create textbox and split data equally as input and display, using javascript

Tags: javascript, split, textbox

Hi I need two input text box fields . Input Field 1 for number of text
   box you want . Input Field 2 for the amount to split. So when I
   submit  i need amount to split equally in the text boxes
   created,using javascript

```js
function divideBy() 
{ 
        num1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}
</script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
            // Number of inputs to create
            var number = document.getElementById("split").value;
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Split " + (i+1)));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "split" + i;
    input.value="split" +i ;
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    
    
    
    
            num1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;

            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="split" name="split" value="">Number of splits: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails"  onclick="addFields()">Create Text Box</a>

 <hr>
 
 
Amount : <input type="text" id="amount" /><br>
 <input type="hidden" id="secondNumber" value="2"  /><br>
<input type="button"  onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "result"></span><br>
    <div value="" id="container"/>
</p>

</body>
```

Comment: please post your tried code..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: If I say I want `3` text boxes and `15` of "amount to split", then 3 text boxes shall be created with value `5` each. Am I right?

Comment: input
No of text box=6
Amount=600

output
[100]
[100]
[100]
[100]
[100]
[100]